# Jest spyOn not working with typescript: "Property 'mockRestore' is missing in type 'Spy'"

Tags: typescript, jestjs

When using [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) with jest and typescript I am getting this type error:

> Type 'Spy' is not assignable to type 'SpyInstance<{}>'.  Property
>   'mockRestore' is missing in type 'Spy'.

Here is a code example that causes it:

```
class A {
  foo = () => this.bar() + 1;
  bar = () => 1;
}

test('should pass', () => {
  const a = new A();
  let barSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
  barSpy = spyOn(a, 'bar');
  a.foo();
  expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

When I run this example the test passes, but the typescript complier fails.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Short Answer

The global `spyOn(...)` function returns a `jasmine.Spy` not a `jest.SpyInstance`. The reason for this, as far as I can tell, is to [ease migration from Jasmine to Jest.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/migration-guide.html)

Here are two options:

```
let barSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
barSpy = jest.spyOn(a, 'bar'); // <--- explicitly use jest.spyOn

// or

let barSpy: jasmine.Spy; // <--- use jasmine.Spy as your type
barSpy = spyOn(a, 'bar');
```

### Further Explanation

The [`node_modules\@types\jest\index.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jest/index.d.ts) file has the Jest type definitions. By looking at them, we can see the two implementations of `spyOn`.

- The `spyOn` that returns a `jest.SpyInstance` is inside the `jest` namespace.
- The `spyOn` that returns a `jasmine.Spy` is in the global namespace.

Unless you're in the process of migrating from Jasmine to Jest, I would use the `jest.spyOn` function instead of the global one.

Comment: I wish this was in the docs in some way - This example  helped me finally make sure that typescript is not telling at me 